# How to do page flip/turn/curl effect in android

Tags: android, flip, cocos2d-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement page curl on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android)

How to do page flipping/turning or curl animation in android ? Is is possible with cocos2d. Please provide any links or example if you know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use ViewFlipper to flip between views. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.

It is possible to assign different animations. [See here for examples](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&source=hp&q=android+viewflipper+example&pbx=1&oq=android+view+flipper+e&aq=0s&aqi=g-s1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=962l3519l0l4505l22l19l0l2l2l0l207l1858l11.7.1l21l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=aff6c11295b9277b&biw=1920&bih=938) or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20view%20flipper).

But it depends on what actually you want to flip and animate. You can draw different shapes and drag or animate them.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated my answer ;)

Comment: I have gone through Curl effect as well as flip effect in android where pages of a book are turned but what i need is turn effect on book means when we have a book with first and last cover as hard bound then the turning style will be different from curl and flip effect.

So please can any one tell me how to implement this and any supporting links or tutorials or examples (are appreciated )

Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Checkout the [Android Page Curl](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)  project:

It has some very nice code for both automated page flips (touch the screen and the page flip animation plays) as manual page flips where the flip actually follows your finger.

Comment: Is it possible to apply curl effect to viewpager. If yes how? Your guidance is important to me. Thanks!!!