# Page curl/turn effect in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement page curl on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android)

I am new to Android. I need a sample code for page flip/curl/turn effect in Android.

Comment: U can perfrom animation pls refer my blog, i had gave detailed explanation there http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/performing-animation-in-android.html

Comment: just See [this](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/archives/master). It will be helpfull to you. There is a Source code also available. . .

Comment: Ready solution - [Natural Page Curl](http://anettosoftware.co.uk/npc.php) technology

Comment: See this Link. http://devappandroid.com/android-beginner/page-curlturn-effect-android It may helping you.