# Layout curl effect in android

Tags: android, animation, view

i want to curl the page on the touch or drag the page to show the curl effect 
like in iphone and ipad. I have searched over the net and came accross this link :-
[Page curl/turn effect in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376962/page-curl-turn-effect-in-android)

but the code listed out there is for curling a bitmap while i want to curl a view

Is there any possibility that using view type animation in android i can achieve this??
The code listed out on the link is heavy to understand bt still is there a possibility that
changing the code above will make me achieve this task??

Comment: Code is listed on this link https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/archives/master