# Curl effect half page in mapView Android

Tags: android, curl, android-mapview, transition, effects

I need to implement half page curl in map view in Android, just like this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYDG1.jpg

I found some libraries, but this libraries works only with bitmap, and i need use it with mapViews or with a layouts.

Sorry for my english, im learning :)

Thanks!!!

Comment: just a thought...you can convert the map to bitmap and then apply this theme...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a possible duplicate that should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376962/page-curl-turn-effect-in-android and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android/