# How to make a flipp effect?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I have an image view and I would like to make flipp effect like this: http://4pda.info/uploads/posts/2012-02/1330251745_3d.png

How do I make it?

PS:

I need animation like flipping pages in a book.

Comment: By flip, do you mean rotating the image? I cannot see any effect on the picture you posted. Did you try anything? Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Have check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376962/page-curl-turn-effect-in-android)
there are so many links provided

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html .

Comment: It is good example but I need animation like flipping pages in a book.