# Page curl (Up and down curl) like it happens in i_phone

Tags: android

Can we have page curl between activities , i have gone through many forum's like Google forum git-hub. but all are for images or view's like layout but nothing i found which can work between activities can any one please help on this.
thanks

Comment: You could have looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376962/page-curl-turn-effect-in-android          which would have pointed you to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android

Comment: nothing works between activities.... i have gone through all these things.....  thanks for your ans. do you know how to use page curl between activities. like if i have activity a and b, a is launcher then i curl activity a and reach to b, how it can be done. your ans will be very help ful.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This guy has implemented it and was kind enough to share the code too. Only watch the video and download the code. And don't forget to give him credit in the code.
https://sites.google.com/site/hnimblog/bai-viet-2/android-hieu-ung-lat-trang-khong-dung-opengl

Comment: it doesn't work.. it is also the same thing which i have got from other site's..
i saw in code.Google.com, that  this is some thing which is not available in android, but still we are looking for some solution, whether any one has the solution please help , i really appreciate every help, i am able to do this, for sure i will share the code with all androidian's

Comment: Ah, ok, I did not pay enough attention to your question. Yes, you cannot do this between activities. This basically works only between views. If you need activities, then you will need to implement the handling of their life cycles, which is basically what Fragments can do for you.

Comment: So if you can use Fragments, then the described solutions should be applicable. Now with Fragments it has become possible to have a single Activity and a number of screens shown by it, and still be able to slice the code into separate functional units. If you are concerned with memory consumption, then you will need to implment some smart Fragment mangement strategy, too. But my suggestion is to start optimization only if your solution is not performing as expected.