# How to get page curl effect for view?

Tags: android

I have seen this example:-  https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl
 for implement page curl effect in android,But in this project use Bitmap ,But My requirement is to achieve this using View.Anyone suggest me?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4376962/1689695

Comment: @TanjaV perhaps You didn't get my question ,I have already see that post but that is for bitmap not for view ,but my requirement for view .If you getting me then reply ?