# where to start for Page flip effect in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-layout, android-widget, page-curl

I have search a lot for page flip effect in android. I found some links. [An example for flip without using OpenGL.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixiekkOD_es)

But I want to implement a 3D real page flip effect for android. same as  [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ)  Or the effect you have seen in IReader for android.
According to my search OpenGL must be use for this. I also search some framework that provide the alternative of OpenGL. But at the end I found nothing.
So I am just want to start OpenGL for this. But I have never ever use OpenGL.
Can any one help me for page flip? some useful link, tutorials, Starting up for OpenGL in android etc...

Comment: I'd guess OpenGL is pretty much mandatory for 'proper' curl effect but check Moss's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android/). If not a feasible solution for your needs, maybe it gives some idea for more proper/faster implementation once you get hold on OpenGL.

Comment: Motivated by your post I started to experiment with curl effect. Take a look if you're interested in implementing your own renderer. It's very much unfinished but am looking forward to have 'proper' implementation one day. Also this is one of the very few OpenGL experiments I've never done so don't look my implementation 'too closely'. [GitHub Link](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl).

Comment: @harism: Great Thanks to you. I am really want to get start for this. I am sure This is the best example for all the people searching for page curl. No other example for android is want to share their code. The create videos and even don't allow to comment on that.
I am sure if you create a blog for this. There will be thousands of like for that.:)
If you like you to like to create a blog with the details of this. Means steps,techniques,algorithms,math,It will be helpful for the thousand of developers.
Thanks again,If you can complete it then it will be more good. I am also trying to complete.

Comment: Dear Harism, Please make your link as a answer. I will accept that answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using this code. Its really really perfect for any one to understand and use. Thanks a lot to [Harism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680519/harism)

[GitHub Link for Page Curl Animation in android With OpenGL](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

Answer (score 0):

here is the one i tried today itself and works fine. [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/browse/#svn/trunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Comment: I have tried this one. No shadow , transparency, it is also slow.
You can batter check it out here. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ)

Comment: Sorry man!! not able to check it now. Youtube is not accessible. will check it later.

Comment: @ Harshad，can you modify your link code to support many images?

Comment: @Arslan your link is great.link i have given is little bit close to it just i dont know how they got effect on back page.otherwise shadow option is there. u can increase it in that code.
@pengwang have not tried that still

Comment: @Arslan you link is great but I cant find a way to download Tiffany api, can u help me ?