# Android page curl effect on layout/s

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I have to curl entire view/layout where I've textview, edittexts, buttons, etc. The task is that I have to curl the entire layout along with those buttons and all. I am not able to understand how to do it in order to curl entire layout instead of just images.

Please help

Comment: please define how one does "curl" a layout

Comment: Sorry, if I am not able to make my question clear. I want to apply curl page effect on layout instead of image so that when I curl the page, textviews, buttons, etc curl along the layout.

Comment: There are quite many questions around Stackoverflow about page curling, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android/).

Comment: @Me-an-Droid is it possible to give the dynamic layout paths in private int[] mBitmapIds?

Comment: HI @Me-an-Droid, did you find any solution for the curl effect for dynamic layouts?

Answer (score 8):

I have done so using the harism github project. All you need to do is grab a bitmap image of the layout by inflating it. Here is the code which replaces the `loadBitmap` function in the `CurlActivity.java`.

```
// Bitmap resources.
private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.layout.infopage0,R.layout.infopage1,
                             R.layout.infopage2, R.layout.infopage3 };

    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
              (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = inflater.inflate(mBitmapIds[index],null);
        v.measure(
                  MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                  MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight()
                    ,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            v.draw(c);          
        return b;
    }
```

The array `mBitmapIds` is now an array of the xml layout id's.

Comment: I am able to handle curling of the layouts, but the problem is how to handle the clicks of the child views? because even a single click on the screen/view is identified as if I want to curl the page.

Comment: this is a bitmap so i guess we will have to manage a callback somehow so that bitmap is replaced with layout.

Comment: @Locutus is it possible to give the dynamic layout paths in private int[] mBitmapIds?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked over Curl effect but I have found a project for you which may help you.

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

Comment: Hi vineet. Thanks for the sample link. I've already used this example to apply curl effect on images but I am not getting how to apply the same on layout.