# How can i curl a layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried those before:

[Android page curl effect on layout/s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180592/android-page-curl-effect-on-layout-s)

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

it's very helpful, but what i want is curl a layout, with Buttons, animations or some controls. 
not just curl a image. please help.