# Android image fipper/curl with zoom

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I'm looking for an image viewer which has zoom functionality (pinch-zoom) and page-flip functionality.

I've found a lot of fancy image viewers and page-flippers out there but I can't find one that has best of both. Is there anything out there what can do this? Or even better, how can I combine an image viewer with a page curl library?

Here is a list of views that I've already tried:

[Android Page Curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)

[Page Turner](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)

[An SO Article here about flipping pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android)

If this is really to hard/impossible to do, it's alright if it's just a swipe animation where the pages get's pushed into the screen.