# Android Book Pages

Tags: android

What's the best way to implement functionality in Android where I have a large amount of text (let's say a book), and I display one page at a time. However, instead of displaying it all at once, and having the user scroll through it, I would want to create it like iBooks where each page is separate, and the user "flips" through it [although, I don't need a fancy flip. A simple slide, like Kindle for iOS, would do].

So how should I go about this? Is creating a customview necessary, or is there some way to do it without that?

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure it works on devices with varying screen sizes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton fill_height, fill_width would cover that, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously asked (I think): [How to do page flip/turn/curl effect in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839117/how-to-do-page-flip-turn-curl-effect-in-android)

Possibly answered: [Implement page curl on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android) with a project at http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

If that doesn't do what you need, you will probably need a custom view, and you'll probably need to do some OpenGL work. The animation and page bending done (to simulate bending the corner of a page) is quite possible but would require some knowledge of the math, which appears to be described at the answer. Your mileage may vary.

EDIT: ah, see [Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

Comment: I know I might not have been clear in the question: but I don't really care for all the fancy flipping stuff. Just a simple slide would also do. I'll update the question to reflect this...

Comment: Okay. That's good. Now how to tie into a book. Like it's probably a waste of resources to have a view for every page. So it would probably make the most sense to have 3/4 views, and keep changing the text as the user flips. So how to do the whole text thing? Or is there a better way?

Comment: A couple of views you slide in and out is probably the way to go: change the text on the off-screen one to the next page and then slide it onto the screen in the right direction.

Comment: One last thing: any way to calculate which text would end up on which page?

Comment: That would depend on font size, spacing, bold text and a bunch of other such items: I've never done much text reflow work but there are typically methods on the Font objects to let you do height and width calculations.

Comment: A pleasure: let me know how the final app turns out.