# Swipe Pages in Android

Tags: android

I have a question that I want to Swipe Screens with touch in Horizontal Manner with Many Pages. Means the background of all these pages are same but Pages over that are different. Same as the WallPaper Screen of any Android Phone which is horizontal Scrollable and Pages are different. How to implement this in our project? PLease suggest me for right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want is a ViewFlipper that android has it since day one.

1) the doc is right here: [ViewFlipper Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

2) Someone asked similar question before here:[ViewFlipper Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839117/how-to-do-page-flip-turn-curl-effect-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should do a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) or an [HorizontalListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877040/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android) (which is not a component from android framework). You can always set a background and the component deals with the swiping behaviour for you !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ViewPager. You can use it after install android compatible packages.
you can get detail infomation from [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).