# FancyOverFlow on swipe listener

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im using this [library](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) to create a gallery,and im kinda new to android programing but i want to add a listener to when the user swipe down the image it will be deleted.
thanks for the helpers,and if you didnt understood me tell me to rephrase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? What errors did you have? Show some effort or you will not get the answers you are expecting.

Comment: @Joel thank you for the respond,i havnt tried anything yet,this is why im asking.i dont know how to do it.i want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you haven't tried anything, and thus you don't have a specific question, all I can do is trying to point you in the right direction (I hope).

I suggest that you do the following:

1) Setup the library: take a look at the [examples provided](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow/tree/master/samples/src/at/technikum/mti/fancycoverflow/samples) by [FancyOverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow).

2) Make sure that you understand what is going on about the code that you use, don't add code "just because it works". Do this as a rule of thumb for every code that you write. If you are using a 3rd party code library, you don't have to fully understand how every method works internally, but make sure that you understand in/outputs of the methods you are calling. Understanding how things work will make it much easier to modify your own code.

3) Find out which component has the hold of your current image in displayed gallery. This will be the control on which you will set up a swipe listener do detect user swipe moves. I haven't tested this, but I suspect taht in this case the component is called `FancyCoverFlow` (take a look at `README.md` file).

4) Take a look at [Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html) (or any tutorial that does swiping) and adapt your code.

If you are new to Android, it may take a while, but don't give up!

Comment: Okay,thanks alot man,can as i understood swipes are Gesture.
any tutorials you recommend on about it?
and i wont give up!:D

Comment: I haven't coded android apps for a while now, but try searching in google or StackOverflow, I'm sure you'll find something. [Here's something to get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607235/swipe-pages-in-android).