# how to add Page curl effect for pdf/images/layout in Android?

Tags: android, page-curl

checked the entire https://android-arsenal.com website but no proper library support available that works right now.

if anyone has anything related to that I can follow and achieve this effect?

page curl effect example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ

tried previous solutions give in the site but those are too old and not working:
[Implement page curl on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android)

[How to do page flip/turn/curl effect in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839117/how-to-do-page-flip-turn-curl-effect-in-android)

Comment: check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: already checked but all these solution are several years old and none of them is working right now.

found one library that might be work for images and testing it right now:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView