# How make curl image animation to slider?

Tags: java, android, android-transitions

The project has already `image slider` successfully with `WiewPagedIndicator` library. I just want to add `curly page animation`. There are few topic for it in StackOverflow. All of them are so old. And I can't implement it to my project. Is there any easier way to add this animation in my project? How can solve this problem?

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
}
```

activity_brochure_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Controllers.BrochureDetailActivity">   
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_activity_borchure_detail"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:centered="true"
        app:fillColor="#df0623"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pager"
        app:pageColor="#fff"
        app:snap="false" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

BrochureDetailActivity.java

```
public class BrochureDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static ViewPager mPager;
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TextView toolbarTextViewBrochureDetail;
    private String imgBrochure, marketNameBrochure, timeBrochure;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brochure_detail);
        sliderPic();
    }
  private void sliderPic(){
      String[] urls;
      if (marketNameBrochure.equals("Carrefour")) {urls = new String[] {getString(R.string.ayuzbir_brochure_url),
              getString(R.string.ayuzbir_brochure_url),getString(R.string.ayuzbir_brochure_url)};
      }
          else {urls = new String[] {getString(R.string.bim_brochure_url)};}

          mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
          mPager.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(BrochureDetailActivity.this, urls));

      CirclePageIndicator indicator =
              findViewById(R.id.indicator);

      indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

      final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

//Set circle indicator radius
      indicator.setRadius(5 * density);

          NUM_PAGES = urls.length;
      // Auto start of viewpager
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                  currentPage = 0;
              }
              mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
          }
      };

      // Pager listener over indicator
      indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

          @Override
          public void onPageSelected(int position) {
              currentPage = position;

          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

          }
      });
}
}
```

Comment: this link should help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839117/how-to-do-page-flip-turn-curl-effect-in-android

Comment: @Mr.Patel sadly. I saw this solution before asking question but I can't implement to my project.